# Updating Multiple Documents in mongodb using mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a list of dictionary like

```
{'data': '[{"url":"https://example1.com/photos-reviews/","score":0.671},{"url":"https://example1.com/concerts-events/concert-organ-performances/2018-2019/","score":0.662},{"url":"https://www.example2.org/support-volunteer/orchestra-league/","score":0.645}]', 'type': 'invalid'}
```

The field `url` is unique and based on the field `type` (invalid or valid - Here invalid), the field `hum_proc` in the mongodb which is by default `null` will be changed to `invalid` or `valid` respectively.

I did this by

```
@sources_api.route('pending_val', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def pending_val():
     if request.method=='POST':
         data_rec = request.get_json()
         if 'type' in data_rec:
             data_list= json.loads(data_rec["data"])
             for val in data_list:
                MlData.objects(url=val["url"]).update_one(set__hum_proc=data_rec["type"])
```

I am iterating and updating each item. Is it possible to update this in a single step more efficiently using aggregation pipeline or so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `update()` method to perform atomic update on fields matched by your query:

`MlData.objects(<your_query>).update(set__hum_proc=data_rec["type"])`

UPDATE:

`update_one()` method overwrites or adds **first** document matched by query, whereas `update()` performs update on **multiple** fields.

I understand you want to update `url`s from request body with equivalent `type` value. You can do that pretty much in one line:

```
MlData.objects(url__in=[e['url'] for e in data_rec['data']]).update(set__hum_proc=data_rec["type"])
```

There are couple notes here.

Firstly, I altered your request json, removing redundant quotes in `data` key, making it more readable:

```
data_rec = {'data': [{"url": "https://example1.com/photos-reviews/",
                      "score": 0.671},
                     {"url": "https://example1.com/concerts-events/concert-organ-performances/2018-2019/",
                      "score": 0.662},
                     {"url": "https://www.example2.org/support-volunteer/orchestra-league/",
                      "score": 0.645}],
            'type': 'valid'}
```

Secondly, I created list of `url` from that json on the fly, which finally allowed me to find those exact values in the database using `in` query operator.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have a doubt again. Whats the difference with the update method I did in the code. Can you update the answer by including the code I added so that I will get a clear idea.

Comment: @imhans4305, sorry for late reply, please check out the edited version of the answer, I hope you will find it helpful.